# Analytics shows a dramatic decrease of sessions but we can't find the cause

Tags: google-analytics

We have contacted Google Adwords, they say they don't have a specialist for Analytics. They advised us to ask our question here.
Since October 6th we have a significant decrease of sessions in Analytics. We can't find out where this decrease comes from. When we choose in Analytics for Acquisition - All Traffic - Channels we see decrease of 28% Paid, decrease of 61% direct, decrease of 91% social and 74% referal. But when we contacted Adwords they looked at it and told us they guess it must be the Merchant campaign. But we checked and can't find dead links or so. So we don't know where to look next. Could someone help us? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Patrick, Adwords support misled you a little - stackoverflow is dedicated to coding problems, so your question is off-top here. There is however a stackexchange site that might be more appropriate, the webmasters site at webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you, will ask my question there!